# The identity element of the Tensor Product of Vector Bundles

Tags: vector-bundles, smooth-manifolds

I want to prove the following:

If $E$ is a smooth vector bundle over $M$, then $(M\times\mathbb{R})\otimes E \simeq E$.

I built an isomorphism between the fibers, but I failed to define an isomorphism between the vector bundles.

Comment: Any good book that deals with vector bundles?

Comment: A vector bundle morphism that is an isomorphism between the fibers is enough.

Answer (score 1):

An isomorphism of vector bundles is just a morphism of vector bundles that is an isomorphism on every fiber (as pointed out by san in a comment).

You say you have an isomorphism between the fibers. I'll assume that the isomorphism you have is $\mathbb{R}\otimes F \to F : r\otimes f\mapsto rf$ where $F$ is a fiber.
Its inverse is $F\to\mathbb{R}\otimes F: f\mapsto 1\otimes f$.

The bundle isomorphism between $E$ and $(M\times\mathbb{R})\otimes E$ is obtained by taking the above isomorphism on every fiber:
$$ (M\times\mathbb{R})\otimes E \to E : (m,r)\otimes f_m \mapsto (rf)_m $$
where I used subscripts to indicate basepoints. The addition of a basepoint in the notation is really the only difference with the vector space case.
The inverse is
$$ E \otimes (M\times\mathbb{R})\otimes E : f_m \mapsto (m,1)\otimes f_m .$$
This answers your question (I hope).

---

(Optional extra paragraph.)

Note that finding the isomorphism of vector bundles was not actually harder than finding the isomorphism between fibers. We just needed to include a basepoint in the notation. This is often true: if you can find a natural map between vector spaces, you get the same map between vector bundles. For example, if $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces then $\text{Hom}(V,W) \cong V^*\otimes W$ by some natural map.
Using the same map but adding basepoints, we get that $$\text{Hom}(D,E) \cong D^*\otimes E$$ where $D$ and $E$ are vector bundles.
(Here by $\text{Hom}(D,E)$ I mean the vector bundle whose fiber over $m$ is $\text{Hom}(D_m,E_m)$. I don't mean the set of vector bundle morphisms from $D$ to $E$.)

Comment: Note that we can always find an isomorphism between the fibers and the $\mathbb{R}^n$. But not every bundle is trivial. Tip of my teacher: define isomorphism locally using smooth local trivialization. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes, you're right, you can always find an isomorphism between a fiber and $\mathbb{R}^n$, but there is no standard choice of such an isomorphism (i.e. the fiber does not have a canonical choice of basis). It is the *naturality* of the isomorphism $\mathbb{R}\otimes F\cong F$ that makes things work. I'm saying things a little vaguely now, and one can make them precise, but it won't fit nicely in a comment.

Comment: (Indeed, a canonical choice of basis in the fibers is nothing but a trivialization of the bundle.)

Comment: It is the  smoothness that I'm worried. How do I show that this isomorphism is a diffeomorphism and is independent of the class representative?

Comment: To show it's a diffeomorphism, you check smoothness of the map and its inverse (which you both know explicitly -- you should probably check that they are indeed inverses). I'm not sure what you mean by class representative.

Comment: The tensor product of the spaces $V$ and $W$ is the following quotient vector space: $V\times W=F(V\times W)/R$ , where $F(V\times W)/R$ is the set of all finite formal linear combinations and $R$ is the sub subspace of $F(V\times W)$ spanned by all elements of the following forms: $(av,w)-a(v,w), (v,aw)-a(v,w), (v_1+v_2,w)-(v_1,w)-(v_2,w),...$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29178/discussion-between-daan-michiels-and-renato-targino).